# Data Preparation

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, data-mining, mixed-type-data

I faced a mixed data set which contained both continuous and categorical variables (totally more than 200 variables). Now I have chosen 60 variables out of them by the business specification.
Then is there any single technique can be used to reduce the dimension further?

I researched decision tree method, but it required all variable as categorical.
PCA/factor analysis etc. were suitable for continuous variable only.

Do I have to transform variables to a single type for process?

Comment: I try to use Gower's distance measure for mixed data.
Hope it works on my real data set.

Comment: To correct your misimpression that PCA and factor analysis are suitable only for continuous variables, please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pca+categorical) for threads about that subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FactorMineR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FactoMineR/index.html) package allows us to perform principal component method for mixed numerical and categorical variables.

More details can be see in the section 3 of [this article](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FactoMineR/vignettes/FactoMineR.pdf).

Comment: *Any* software that does PCA will work on any kind of variable at all.  What, then, are you actually recommending and why?